# Не запускается загрузочная флешка с windows 7 из под linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

В общем дело было так: из-под моей основой ос (windows 7) записал образ linux mint на флешку, все установил. В итоге при запуске системы не появляется окна выбора ос, система все время грузится в линукс. 
После этого я записал из-под линукс образ виндоус 7 на флешку, в boot меню биоса ставил флешку на первое место, но все-равно запускается именно линукс. При этом с другими дистрибутивами в принципе все работало. 
Проблема именно в том, что окно GRUB не появляется при запуске и я никак не могу ни загрузиться в виндоус, ни его переустановить.

Comment: P.S "При этом с другими дистрибутивами в принципе все работало" - я имел в виду, что я могу запустить из загрузочной флешки например тот же Rescatux.

Comment: Ну и как я понял, у меня именно BIOS, а не UEFI (посмотрел в терминале "ls sys/firmware/efi" - отсутствует)

Comment: для виндовс 7 нужен правильный mbr для запуска с флешки.

Answer (score 0):

чтоб сделать флешку с виндовс загрузочной её нужно поправить командой

```
ms-sys -m /dev/sdb
```